# How we can avoid unwanted detection

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

Currently I am doing face detection from video images. I am able to detect faces from videos. I am using Haar cascade classifier for that. *But it shows some unwanted detection* that is it detect some region that is not a face.

What should I do to avoid this unwanted detection. In my program I am using `cvHaarDetectObject()` function. Is there any wrong with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh, please use CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale() instead of cvHaarDetectObject(), as the old c-api is deprecated and will restrict you to using haar-cascades only (can't use lbp or hog from c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to avoid some unwanted detection of images from videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950378/how-to-avoid-some-unwanted-detection-of-images-from-videos)

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the corresponding parameters for [`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) to suit your purpose, i.e. filter out unwanted faces.

During these parameters, you need to pay more attention to four of them:

- **scaleFactor** – Parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale.
- **minNeighbors** – Parameter specifying how many neighbors each candidate rectangle should have to retain it.
- **minSize** – Minimum possible object size. Objects smaller than that are ignored.
- **maxSize** – Maximum possible object size. Objects bigger than that are ignored.